# Why my code not able to add activity?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm, xrmservicetoolkit

I am trying to add phonecall activity for contact. I used following code to add activity, but I cannot see it in activity list.

```
var ContactId = guid; //Contact GUID

var trigger = new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity("phonecall");
trigger.attributes["subject"] = "Hello";
trigger.attributes["regardingobjectid"] =
                     { id: ContactId, logicalName: "Contact", type: "EntityReference" };

triggerId = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(trigger);

}
```

Kindly suggest if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in contact as the logicalName.
This:

```
{ id: ContactId, logicalName: "Contact", type: "EntityReference" };
```

should be:

```
{ id: ContactId, logicalName: "contact", type: "EntityReference" };
```